# How create blending ensemble properly and call as ussual Libary, how to integrate in below my model

Tags: python, regression, ensemble-learning, machine-learning-model

`Objective is create ensemble model including tuning params from weak learner and integrate with my model always problem`

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [19], in <cell line: 1>()
----> 1 ensemble.train_and_predict('MK1', model_name='Blending', param_grid=param_grid_bl)

Input In [15], in EnsembleRegressor.train_and_predict(self, sheet, model_name, param_grid)
     30     raise ValueError(f"Invalid model name: {model_name}")
     32 # Parameter tuning
---> 33 best_params, results = self.tune_parameters(model_class, x_train, y_train, param_grid)
     35 # Train the model with the best parameters
     36 model = model_class(**best_params)

Input In [15], in EnsembleRegressor.tune_parameters(self, model_class, X, y, param_grid)
     59 results = []
     61 for params in self.grid_search(param_grid):
---> 62     model = model_class(**params)
     63     model.fit(X, y)
     64     y_pred = model.predict(X)

TypeError: __call__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'knn_k'
```

This is my BlendingModel :

```
class BlendingEnsemble():
    def __init__(self, knn_k=5, rf_n_estimators=100, svr_c=1.0):
        self.models = []
        self.blender = None
        self.knn_k = knn_k
        self.rf_n_estimators = rf_n_estimators
        self.svr_c = svr_c

    def get_models(self):
        models = []
        models.append(('knn', KNeighborsRegressor(n_neighbors=self.knn_k)))
        models.append(('rf', RandomForestRegressor(n_estimators=self.rf_n_estimators)))
        models.append(('svm', SVR(C=self.svr_c)))
        return models


    def fit(self, X_train, y_train):
        self.models = self.get_models()

        X_train, X_val, y_train, y_val = train_test_split(X_train, y_train, test_size=0.33, random_state=1)

        # Fit all models on the training set and predict on the holdout set
        meta_X = []
        for name, model in self.models:
            # Fit model on the training set
            model.fit(X_train, y_train)
            # Predict on the holdout set
            yhat = model.predict(X_val)
            # Reshape predictions into a matrix with one column
            yhat = np.atleast_2d(yhat).T
            # Store predictions as input for blending
            meta_X.append(yhat)

        # Create 2D array from predictions, each set is an input feature
        meta_X = np.hstack(meta_X)

        # Define blending model
        blender = RandomForestRegressor()

        # Fit on predictions from base models
        blender.fit(meta_X, y_val)
        self.blender = blender

        return blender

    def predict(self, X_test):
        # Make predictions with base models
        meta_X = []
        for _, model in self.models:
            # Predict with base model
            yhat = model.predict(X_test)
            # Reshape predictions into a matrix with one column
            yhat = np.atleast_2d(yhat).T
            # Store prediction
            meta_X.append(yhat)

        # Create 2D array from predictions, each set is an input feature
        meta_X = np.hstack(meta_X)

        # Predict
        return self.blender.predict(meta_X)
    def evaluate_r2(self, y_true, y_pred):
        return r2_score(y_true, y_pred)

    def evaluate_rmse(self, y_true, y_pred):
        return np.sqrt(mean_squared_error(y_true, y_pred))
    def __call__(self, X):
        return self.predict(X)
```

I want to integrate with my modeling regression like below :

```
class EnsembleRegressor:
    def __init__(self, data_source_file, result_file,params_file):
        self.data_source_file = data_source_file
        self.result_file = result_file
        self.params_file = params_file
        blending = BlendingEnsemble()
        self.models = {
            'Blending':blending ,
            'XGBoost': xgb.XGBRegressor,
            'RandomForest': RandomForestRegressor
        }
    

    def train_and_predict(self, sheet, model_name='Blending', param_grid=None):
        # Splitting features and label
        data = pd.read_excel(self.data_source_file, sheet_name=sheet)
        X = data.drop(columns='Earned Value')
        y = data['Earned Value']

        # Splitting data into training and testing sets
        x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, train_size=0.8, random_state=58)
        x_train = x_train.sort_index(ascending=True)
        y_train = y_train.sort_index(ascending=True)
        x_test = x_test.sort_index(ascending=True)
        y_test = y_test.sort_index(ascending=True)

        # Model selection
        model_class = self.models.get(model_name)
        if model_class is None:
            raise ValueError(f"Invalid model name: {model_name}")

        # Parameter tuning
        best_params, results = self.tune_parameters(model_class, x_train, y_train, param_grid)

        # Train the model with the best parameters
        model = model_class(**best_params)
        model.fit(x_train, y_train)
        
        # Predict on the test set
        x_test.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)

        ev_pred = model.predict(x_test)

        # Create a DataFrame with predictions
        perform = pd.DataFrame({'AT':x_test.iloc[:,0].values,'Planned Value':x_test.iloc[:,1].values,
                                'Actual': y_test.values, 'EV_Pred': ev_pred, 'Model': model_name})
        results ['Model']=model_name
        # Save the results to Excel files
        self.to_excel(perform, self.result_file, sheet)
        self.to_excel(results, self.params_file, sheet)

    def tune_parameters(self, model_class, X, y, param_grid=None):
        if param_grid is None:
            param_grid = {}  

        # Grid search to find the best parameters
        best_params = None
        best_score = float('inf')
        results = []

        for params in self.grid_search(param_grid):
            model = model_class(**params)
            model.fit(X, y)
            y_pred = model.predict(X)
            r2 = self.evaluate_r2(y, y_pred)
            rmse = self.evaluate_rmse(y, y_pred)

            results.append({**params, 'R2': r2, 'RMSE': rmse})

            if rmse < best_score:
                best_score = rmse
                best_params = params

        results_df = pd.DataFrame(results)
        return best_params, results_df

    @staticmethod
    def grid_search(param_grid):
        keys, values = zip(*param_grid.items())
        for combination in itertools.product(*values):
            yield dict(zip(keys, combination))

    @staticmethod
    def evaluate_r2(y_true, y_pred):
        return r2_score(y_true, y_pred)

    @staticmethod
    def evaluate_rmse(y_true, y_pred):
        return np.sqrt(mean_squared_error(y_true, y_pred))
    
    @staticmethod
    def to_excel(df, file, sheet_name):
        try:
            book = load_workbook(file)
            writer = pd.ExcelWriter(file, engine='openpyxl')
            writer.book = book
            writer.sheets = dict((ws.title, ws) for ws in book.worksheets)

            if sheet_name in writer.sheets:
                sheet = writer.sheets[sheet_name]
                last_row = sheet.max_row
            else:
                last_row = 0

            if last_row < 1:
                df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name=sheet_name, index=False)
            else:
                df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name=sheet_name, index=False, header=True, startrow=last_row)

            writer.save()
        except FileNotFoundError:
            df.to_excel(file, sheet_name=sheet_name, index=False)
```

Please some one to help me, stuck for finding the solution

i try for connecting my blendingmodel as a normal ML modeling like fit and predict. i just expecting my blendingensemble can connect with my regression modeling